# Fonts looks different in Safari

Tags: browser, fonts, safari

I have problem with Safari and Google fonts. I use Lato google webfont and looks good in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari it looks really bad. The problem is the site is "designed" for that font and in Safari the font is bigger and breaks the look.
So it seems like its not loading correct.

I use a template for Joomla to assign the Google fonts and have checked that it loads the google style sheet as https but from there im lost?
www . printdk . de

[image: Font in Chrome]

[image: Font in Safari]

Comment: There questions at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082632/1983389 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/30876894/1983389 have answers that explain what is happening.

Comment: I tried almost everything. But i found out that my template ads this link to the font. There is only "normal" font weight assigned. Shouldnt there be "bold" 700 also ?  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: Yes, i found out that my template was only loading the normal. So when i added Bold to the link it looks good in Safari also.