# Difference in font rendering for U+200A

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, utf-8, webfonts

I'm having a strange issue in font-rendering differences between latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

I'm using a [hair space character](https://www.utf8icons.com/character/8202/hair-space) with a font stack as follows: 
`font-family: "Verdana", "Geneva", sans-serif;`

I haven't found a reliable resource what's going wrong but there's a clear difference in rendering this character:

<kbd>**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nirazul/pen/YZbqNN?editors=1100)**</kbd>

What I've found out so far:

- Chrome seems to render the hair space in Verdana
- Firefox isn't able to do this and falls back to Times New Roman
- Geneva seems to have a glyph for this character but it's the same width as a normal space (rendering it useless)

The main question is: Why is Verdana behaving differently in Chrome and Firefox. Both use the same system font.

**[EDIT]**
I've added an animated gif to show you the difference I'm experiencing. Apart from minor tweaks to the line heights I haven't changed the base images. The rendering is alsmost completely different except the hair space. Maybe this is a macOS specific problem:

[image: Animation]

Comment: Browser use different font rendering engine and in different bowser and different SO you may have very different behaving of the same font. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876894/how-to-prevent-different-browsers-rendering-fonts-differently

Comment: I'm aware of this, however this is a problem of glyphs not being used at all. This has nothing to do with actual rendering.

Comment: @Nirazul I don't see it. Here is a screenshot of the two browsers side by side on Windows 8.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw1hU.jpg

Comment: @MrLister So this might be a system dependent issue. Thanks for posting your screenshot! I've added an animated gif to show what I see on macOS.