# Font-weight issue in different browser, same font looks different in different browser

Tags: css, cross-browser

I am working on Asp.net MVC application.

In my application the text is displayed looks less bold in chrome than Firefox.

Chrome:

[image]

FireFox:

[image]

This is my css:

```
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333;
    background: #f2f6f7;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Is there anything that I can changed in the code to get the same feel across all browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent different browsers rendering fonts differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876894/how-to-prevent-different-browsers-rendering-fonts-differently)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` worth noting that all browsers have their own rendering engine so it might not be possible to get it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in Firefox:

`-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`

Alternatively, if you don't want the thinner font, you could disable the font-smoothing in Chrome:

`-webkit-font-smoothing: unset;`