# Fonts look different in different browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, render

This is how browsers will currently render my website fonts:

[image]

I tried several css parameters found for the web like:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

/* and others */
```

But nothing worked.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent different browsers rendering fonts differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876894/how-to-prevent-different-browsers-rendering-fonts-differently)

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers require different font files for rendering. 
You can upload a font to [this site](https://transfonter.org/) and choose the font types you would like (I suggest TTF, EOT, WOFF and WOFF2) and it will ZIP up a file including the different font types for you to use on your project.